# How to bring item to front in FastReport in runtime?

Tags: runtime, fastreport

When placing items on FastReport bands, there is a command in designer, to bring item to back or to front. But, there is no such method that can be called in runtime from the script.

```
begin
  Memo86.BringToFront; // No such method
end.
```

How to bring items to back or to front from FastReport script in runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I have found is to do this manually through items parent band:

```
begin
  // BringToFront
  Memo86.Parent.Objects.Remove(Memo86);
  Memo86.Parent.Objects.Add(Memo86);

  // BringToBack
  Memo86.Parent.Objects.Remove(Memo86);
  Memo86.Parent.Objects.Insert(0, Memo86);
end.
```